# Matlab, struct to matrix form with matrices oriented the correct way

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct

I have a struct called poseSets and it contains two things:

1. Pose
2. Time

So what I want to do is to get the poses (Pose is a 4x4 matrix) in to one big long `(4xN_Poses) x 4` matrix.

So lets imagine that i have a list of structs that is 10 long. I can get almost my list by doing this:

```
[structList.Pose]
```

But this gives me a `(4xN) x 4` matrix ie:

```
1 2 3 4 | 1 2 3 4 | 1 2 3 4 | ...
5 6 7 8 | 5 6 7 8 | 5 6 7 8 | ...
3 5 6 8 | 3 5 6 8 | 3 5 6 8 | ...
0 0 0 1 | 0 0 0 1 | 0 0 0 1 | ...
```

But what i really want is this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
3 5 6 8
0 0 0 1
_______ 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
3 5 6 8
0 0 0 1
_______ 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
3 5 6 8
0 0 0 1
_______ 
: : : :
```

Now i cant transpose it because each of the matrices would be individually transposed and would be the wrong way.

Now you can solve this with a for loop:

```
poseList = [];

for i = 1:length(PoseSets);
    poseList = [poseList; PoseSets(i).Pose];
end
```

Note: poseList contains what i want.

But I personally believe that matlab is magic and you should be able to write what you want in english and matlab will deliver. Does anyone know a one liner or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I also find this quite annoying...some things in Matlab do not seem consistent regarding row-majorness or column-majorness. This is one example where things are concatenated colum-wise (=row-major), while the vast majority of algorithms are column-major. `linspace` or generic ranges (e.g., `x = 0:5:100`) are another prime example of row-major matrix generation, while `x(:)` is then again column-major... ¯\(°_°)/¯

Anyway, the easiest way to resolve is to force column-major concatenation:

```
cat(1, structList.Pose)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this: `vertcat(structList.Pose)`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but is sure isn't a one-liner:

```
% generate some data
M = magic(4)
poseSets = struct('pose',M);
poseSets = repmat(poseSets,3,1)

poseList = cellfun(@transpose, {poseSets.pose}, 'UniformOutput', false);
poseList = [poseList{:}].'
```